# The import org.apache.poi.xssf can not be resolved

Tags: java, excel, apache, maven

I've created Maven project and in pom.xml, I've mentioned following POI dependency in order to read from and write to excel file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

In test, when I add `import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;`, I don't see any error.

However when I add `import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;`, it shows an error: `The import org.apache.poi.xssf can not be resolved`

It's throwing error for XSSF but not for HSSF. Can you guide me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

for Poi/XSSF you need also dependency to `poi-ooxml`, like so

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have added both:

    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Still it is not detected...

Comment: @EyalSooliman `<scope>test</scope>` is likely not what you want

Comment: This is not the sulotion. But I have found a way to override: I just changed to HSSF instead of XSSF.

Comment: If I want to read only XLSX files, then importing just ooxml library would do? and not importing hssf library?

Answer (score 4):

**Look for "poi-3.17.jar"!!!**

1. Download from "https://poi.apache.org/download.html".
2. Click the one Binary Distribution -> poi-bin-3.17-20170915.tar.gz
3. Unzip the file download and look for this "poi-3.17.jar".

Problem solved and errors disappeared.

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 2):

When using maven, for Apache POI, make sure to add all the latest dependencies related to Apache POI as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
<dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Save and run.
Errors should be resolved.